# created regex to ignore .goutputstream files

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I created a watcher with `chokidar` which worked properly but then now I want to ignore some files with regex but doesn't seem to be working though.

What have I done wrong with this code or regex?

here is my code

```
const watcher = chokidar.watch(process.env.WATCH_PATH, {
    // ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../,
    ignored: [/^.goutputstream/],
    persistent: true
});
```

EDIT:
My bad, I wanted anything that starts with `.goutputstream` so could be `.goutputstream-blahblahblah`

Comment: Do you mean to match any string ending with `.goutputstream`? Try `/\.goutputstream$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my bad, I edited my question and I wanted to start with instead of ending with

Comment: So, you wanted `/^\.goutputstream\b/`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no luck with that

Comment: Please (re)read Anders Kaseorg's response, and upvote and "Accept" it if it works.  As he points out, you have (at least) two issues: 1) you need to escape the period - `\.`, 2) If `.goutputstream` is *REALLY* the beginning of the text, you can use `/^\.goutputstream`.  Otherwise, if there's a leading path, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- `.` matches any character, you need to write `\.` to match (only) a period.
- `^` only matches at the beginning of the string, but you’re probably getting `some/path/.goutputstream` which doesn’t match your pattern at the beginning of the string.  (That’s why the commented regex began `(^|[\/\\])`, which matches either the beginning of the string, or a slash or backslash character.)

Comment: what you meant is doing something like `/(^|[\/\\])\.goutputstream./` ? I always `split and pop` so I get the `filename` which would make `.` the beginning but doesn't really matter.  The commented regex is the original sample but I do not want to ignore all `.` file/folder though so that's why I want to specify which to ignore.

Comment: Well, did you try it? Note again that `.` matches any character, so by putting `.` at the end of your regex this time, you’ve told `chokidar` to only ignore filenames with a character after `.goutputstream` (i.e. `.goutputstream` is not at the end); is that what you meant? Also, it doesn’t matter what you do to the filename after getting it back from `chokidar`, with `split` and `pop` or anything else (by the way, there’s [`path.basename`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext) for that), because the regex test already happened.

Comment: sryz I am really really bad with regex.  Yes I have tried after I replied you but doesn't seem to help much.  To make it simple as long as the string contains `.goutputstream` I want to ignore so if it's `.goutputstream-fiDMeifnd`, `hello/.goutputstream-blah`, `.goutputstream_anything`